# How can you be confident that Subversion's automatic merges don't introduce logical conflicts?

Tags: svn, testing, merge

`svn update` does automatic merges when it thinks it can. Shouldn't there be a pre-requisite or something? If you work in an organization where unit/regression tests are mainly during QA testing, how on earth can anyone be confident that the merge did not create an insidious bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience conflcts hapen more often than the documentation says. Most are easy to solve but they must be solved.

Comment: So this is what confuses me. Without rigorous regression testing, you would not even be ABLE to find the bug. this should be causing all sorts of problems or am I the only one that is in a place without massive testing ? Or is there some thing process that people follow to avoid this kind of thing. How are people blithely checking in code that may actually have an issue ...

Comment: @mafalda the automatic merges are done on `svn update` in the working copy, and leave the working copy in a non-committed state. There are no automatic commits of the merged results.

Comment: I understand there is no automatic commit.  yikes- that would be even scarier. but its very tedious to figure out if the merge broke your code if you are able to build and run tests as soon as you merge- albeit only locally

Comment: I don't see this as an answer to the question. @mafalda, I suggest that you accept the other one instead.

Answer (score 3):

> If you work in an organization where
>   unit/regression tests are mainly
>   during QA testing how on earth can
>   anyone be confident that the merge did
>   not create an insidious bug ?

You should review your changes right before you commit them. Whether you `svn update`d the base revision a few time while you were working shouldn't matter, the final changes are always against the latest version in the repository and that is what you should review.

More importantly: how can you be sure that *any* commit doesn't horribly break everything if you don't run tests *before* your commit? Developers should at least run and maintain the unit tests.

(Mind you, there are other reasons why merges by `svn update` can be a pain: if you get conflicts that are difficult to resolve, it's sometimes a bit too easy to get in a situation were you can no longer salvage your local changes. But that's another story, as forcing conflicts would just make the problem worse...)